Livewire component not received the event sent by Livewire.dispatchTo
I tried to dispatch an event to a livewire component, but the event was not received.
In my app.js I have :
window.Echo.channel('channel-place')
    .listen('.PlaceAddedEvent', (e) => {
        console.log('PlaceAddedEvent received:', e); // Vérifiez si ce message apparaît dans la console du navigateur
    
        if (typeof window.Livewire !== 'undefined') {
                console.log("dispatchto");
                Livewire.dispatchTo('places-table', 'PlaceAddedEvent', { message: 'Test' });
                console.log('Dispatch finished');
        } else {
            console.error('Livewire is not available.');
        }
});

And it seems to work, I don't have any errorr, the string "'Dispatch finished" is displayed in the console.
Here is my Livewire PHP component :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Search;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Livewire\Attributes\On; 

class PlacesTable extends Component
{

      #[On('PlaceAddedEvent')] 
      public function handlePlaceAdded($payload)
      {
            Log::info('PlaceAddedEvent RECEIVED :', $payload);
            $this->render();
      }

    public function mount($searchId)
    {
        $this->searchId = $searchId;

        // it works
        //  $this->dispatch('PlaceAddedEvent', ['message' => 'Test direct interne']);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        //
    }

}

In my blade file :
@livewire('places-table', ['searchId' => $search->id])

As you can see, the component name places-table match with the dispatchTo method, as well as the event name.
When I try to dispatch the event from the same blade that included the livewire, it doesn't work :
<button wire:click="$dispatch('PlaceAddedEvent', { message: 'Test Button' })">
    Test Event Dispatch
</button>

But when I displatch it from the PHP component itself, it works :
$this->dispatch('PlaceAddedEvent', ['message' => 'Test direct interne']);

Any clue?
Thanks

OK it found it.
It was because the name of the variable "message" has to match with the argument of the method :
public function handlePlaceAdded($payload)
{
Log::info('PlaceAddedEvent RECEIVED :', $payload);
$this->render();
}
I had to repalce "$payload" by "$message"
